# how to convert date format to datetime format using php

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

**It is not work for me, i want to convert date format to datetime of mysql format using php.i have try to obtain through the below code.what is wrong with my code**

```
    $travelDatesconv=strtotime($travelDate);       //15/03/2015

         $travelDates=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($travelDatesconv));

            echo $travelDates."=>uu";        
          //i need 2015-03-15 00:00:00
```

Comment: what is the result in `$travelDate` ?

Comment: 15/03/2015 output => 1970-01-01 05:30:00=>uu

Comment: check the code i have updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the DateTime object in PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)?

Here is how i would do it:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $travelDate);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

eliminate ."=>uu" and strtotime do not work with the format 15/03/2015 you must change $travelDate something like '03/15/2015'

```
$travelDate = '03/05/2015';
$travelDates = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($travelDate));
echo $travelDates;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the code

```
$travelDatesconv=strtotime($travelDate);       //15/03/2015
 $travelDates=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($travelDatesconv));
 echo $travelDates;        
 //Result 2015-03-15 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code,

```
$travelDatesconv=strtotime($travelDate);       //15/03/2015

    $travelDates=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$travelDatesconv);

    echo $travelDates."=>uu";
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: what's different to your code and me..bro

Comment: @UdayaRavi check this line $travelDates=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$travelDatesconv);

Answer (score 0):

```
$travelDate = '15/03/2015';

$date        = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', "$travelDate 00:00:00");
$travelDates = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "=>uu";

echo $travelDates . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
2015-03-15 00:00:00=>uu
```